# retrieving all rules inserted into drools session which are being printed in KieSession using drools query

Tags: java, drools

I am having a number of rules which are inserted in the drools session and I've got them printed using event listener provided by KieSession. Here is the code:

```
  kSession.addEventListener(new RuleRuntimeEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("==> " + event.getObject() + " inserted");
        }

        @Override
        public void objectUpdated(ObjectUpdatedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("==> " + event.getObject() + " updated");

        }

        @Override
        public void objectDeleted(ObjectDeletedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("==> " + event.getOldObject() + " deleted");
        }
    });
```

I want to get all the rules printed in objectInserted and are not triggered by objectDeleted method using drools query. I am not finding a way to do that. I don't want to it using Java but Drools. I am new to drools and did not find much regarding this over the internet. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

**What I am trying to do**
I am trying to write a query that returns me all the values which are present in a drool session using drools query.
something like this:

```
query "Query all attack categories"
AttackCategory($category : value)
end
```

this is a query i am already using in my system. I want this query to be generified and fetch all the objects(of different classes ) with only a single query.

**My KieBaseModel**

```
     KieBaseModel kbaseModel = kmoduleModel
            .newKieBaseModel(DEFAULT_KIE_BASE_NAME)
            .setDefault(true)
            .setEqualsBehavior(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY)
            .setEventProcessingMode(EventProcessingOption.CLOUD);
```

**Update to the requirements**
I can get the Objects from the drolls but is there any way I can get a tree structure as defined in the image. I want to get a link between the questions as well. Like, if question 1 was answered, which question was asked after it, and if the level 1 q1 was asked, then which question was asked after that. Some of the questions will be deleted from the tree as well. I need the connected tree-like described in the image. Is there any way to get such a tree from drools? Thanks

[image: tree structure]

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to [do] it using Java" -- you're using Java in your own example. ?

Comment: yeah. I am using java. What I meant is that I want to get the rules inserted in session which are not deleted when the session ends or it reaches at a condition i have before it, I want to use a query of drools to fetch those available values in seesion. I hope you understand the question.

Comment: If you're going to be using a listener -- which is how I'd do it -- it's still going to be written in Java. You're going to need to show an example of what you mean "do it in Drools" because I have no idea what you're asking for. (Even an example rule showing why you'd want to do this might be helpful.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have updated the question. Please have a look. I want to fetch all the available values as I want to generate a structure when the user ends answering the questions and in that structure which I will show as a tree, I want to show the user that which path did he followed and what were the end results.

Comment: Are you using drools in stream mode? is that why you're referencing continual actions (eg answering subsequent questions?)

Comment: No. I am on cloud mode. Having this line in my app
setEventProcessingMode(EventProcessingOption.CLOUD);

Comment: I have added my KieBaseModel in the question. Hope that gives some hints

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your DRL file(s) you have access to a variable called `drools`. This is an instance of the [`KnowledgeHelper` class](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/spi/KnowledgeHelper.java), which gives you access to a bunch of information about the rules, environment, working memory, etc. The link is to the source code for `KnowledgeHelper`, since the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-THEN-methods-variables-ref_drl-rules) only discusses the most commonly used methods (usually for getting stuff like the rule name.)

From the `drools` variable, you can access the [`WorkingMemory` object](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/f4c076ea2ddc63becdc58d4234030e67e8437225/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/WorkingMemory.java) (link to source), which gives you access to all the objects in working memory. You should be able to use `iterateObjects` or `iterateFactHandles` to walk the data in working memory as needed.

Obviously I'm not familiar with your specific use case, so you'll need to update any code to match your use case. But let's say I want to get all `AttackCategory` instances remaining in WorkingMemory, I might do something like this:

```
drools.getWorkingMemory()
      .iterateObjects(new ObjectFilter() {
          @Override
          public boolean accept(Object object) {
            return object instanceOf AttackCategory;
          }
       ) // now you have an instance of Iterator<? extends AttackCategory>
```

You could also substitute `iterateFactHandles` for `iterateObjects` if you wish to iterate over the fact handles instead.

Note that these iterators are not threadsafe.

You could alternatively do this in Java and call such a utility method from the DRL, but you indicated you'd prefer to do this in Drools itself. Unfortunately while drools does give you access to working memory and the general environment, the listeners are outside of this. Drools is only aware of facts in its working memory, but not how they got there. The way listeners work is that they hook into the `insert` and `delete` handlers themselves and trigger when those methods do; the objects, once inserted, are just like any other object in working memory (which is to say, you can't differentiate between how they got there.)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I will try this method.

Comment: Please have a look at the question. I have updated a few things. thanks

Comment: You've changed the question to be something completely different now. No you can't get a tree structure.

Comment: We are thinking about it as a decision tree. We want to get to know about which parent produced which child. is that possible using Java or Drools or using some listeners in Java?

Comment: Java has tree data structures, use of those those and populated as needed. It's not really relevant to the question you asked, though, which is how to get the objects from memory.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas why would you do that? Suggesting to iterate the working memory objects is just wrong. To get a specific instance of an object you use the pattern matching on the LHS

Comment: Obviously I don't think any of this should be done. But you _can_ if you have to. The OP's application is not properly designed for using Drools but that ship sailed about a dozen questions ago.